# how to manually update add android:exported in the flutter package

Tags: flutter

the application cannot be uploaded to the playstore with the reason that it must define android:exported, even though I have defined it in the flutterProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, but the error remains the same, I suspect because the package I am using is old school,

I want to update it manually but the manifest is just like below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.onesignal.flutter">
</manifest>
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
   <application
        android:label="App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>


       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" //here ------
```

---

you need to add this in **Activity Tag**
(Must Add Launcher Activity : android:exported="true")

Comment: the code above is for the new version of flutter, while I'm using version 1.22.6, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: clear cache and try again . (delete .build folder)

Comment: it has no effect on the version